Why Inclusion tags not working in Django?
I want to use inclusion tags to display the sidebar, but nothing is displayed.
templatetags/sidebar_tags.py
from ..models import Post
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('blog/include/post-category.html')
def post_category():
    return {'posts': Post.objects.all()}

post-category.html
<div class="single-sidebar-widget post-category-widget">
    <h4 class="category-title">Post Categories</h4>
    <ul class="cat-list">
        {% for category in posts.categories.all %}
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <p>{{ category.name }}</p>
                <p>37</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

home.html
{% load sidebar_tags %}
{% post_category %}

I think the code is ok but I don't know why it works

Only one reason, why it can not appears - registered tag dont see the template.
btw. Don't import Posts in Tag.
You can add "objests_list" in context, and in tag you can use template context.
And for standart list view django do it automatically.
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/include/post-category.html', takes_context=True)
def post_category(context):
    return {'posts': context['objects_list']}

But if you want in this case to render list of objects, you dont need inclusion tag at all:
in home.html:
{% load sidebar_tags %}
{% include 'blog/include/post-category.html' with posts=objects_list %}

